# How to increase line width of line-charts?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

Is there any option available for increasing the line width of line-charts? I have tried to alter the `stroke`, but that does not seem to have any affect.

Here is how the line-chart is initialized:

```js
paper.linechart(10, 30, 400, 240, [
    [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
], [
    [15, 10, 20, 14, 13, 17, 9],
    [7, 13, 17, 9, 10, 20, 14],
    [5, 4, 14, 12, 20, 3, 16]
]);
```

Comment: If you include a jsfiddle of your code helping would be easier!

Answer (score 1):

Currently your only option would be to specify a higher `width` value in the options. From the [documentation](http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.linechart), under the `width` property of `Paper.lineChart`'s options:

> (`width`) controls the size of the plotted symbol. Also controls the thickness
>   of the line using a formula stroke-width=width/2.

To only control the line's `stroke-width`, you should be able to pass an empty `symbol` and the desired `width` value to the opts, e.g.:

```js
paper.linechart(10, 30, 400, 240, [
    [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
], [
    [15, 10, 20, 14, 13, 17, 9],
    [7, 13, 17, 9, 10, 20, 14],
    [5, 4, 14, 12, 20, 3, 16]
], {
    symbol: '',
    width: 5
});
```

*(You can pass `circle` as a symbol, of course, but its size will be derived from the `width` value).*